# In CheckBox tree view not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i click on Electronics `ID value = option` it will enable the check box laptop,tvs,microphone except Electronics new. In case i click on Electronics new `Id value =option1` it should enable all check box like Electronics,Electronics new,Laptop,TVS,Microphone but in  my code it is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.subOption'),
    checkall = document.getElementById('option');

for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
    var checkedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input.subOption:checked').length;

    checkall.checked = checkedCount > 0;
    checkall.indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxes.length;
  }
}

checkall.onclick = function() {
  for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
  }
}
 });
```

```css
body {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

hr {
  margin: 50px 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.container {
  margin: 40px auto;
  max-width: 700px;
}

li {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option"><label for="option"> Electronics</label>
      <ul>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option1"><label for="option1"> Electronics new</label>
    <ul>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> Laptops</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> TVs</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> Microphones</label></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/tgzfzz05/)**

Comment: Also if select `Microphones` should check [minus] on `Electronics new` and `Electronics` right?

Comment: yes sir  @Mr.x..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix a few things:

- Firstly, your unordered list structure is messed up. You need to have each `<ul>` in another `<li>` if you're nesting them.
- You didn't include a function to check when "Electronics new" is checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.subOption'),
    checkall = document.getElementById('option'),
    checkall1 = document.getElementById('option1');

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
      var checkedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input.subOption:checked').length;

      checkall.checked = checkedCount > 0;
      checkall1.checked = checkedCount > 0;
      checkall1.indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxes.length;
      checkall.indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxes.length;
    }
  }

  checkall.onclick = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
      checkall1.checked = this.checked;
    }
  }

  checkall1.onclick = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
      checkall.checked = this.checked;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

hr {
  margin: 50px 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.container {
  margin: 40px auto;
  max-width: 700px;
}

li {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option"><label for="option"> Electronics</label>
    </li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option1"><label for="option1"> Electronics new</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> Laptops</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> TVs</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> Microphones</label></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: when i click on `Electronics ID value = option` it will enable the check box Electronics new,laptop,tvs,microphone

Comment: Yes, it is excluding electronics new. That's what you mentioned.

Comment: when i click on Laptops it will enable the check box Electronics and Electronics new

Comment: Oh both of them?

Comment: when i click Electronics that time Electronics new is not clicked check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161353/discussion-between-ivin-raj-and-highdef).

Comment: "When i click on Electronics ID value = option it will enable the check box laptop,tvs,microphone except Electronics new." That's what you asked.